# How to assign entries to static positions such as footer?

Tags: entries, link

The footer of my site has some links that can be considered "static" in the sense that they always should point to a specific entry. One for "acknowledgements", one for "cookie info" and one for "more contact info".

What is the recommended way to assign entries to these three "roles"? I need it to work in a multi-site envionment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use case for an [Entries field](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/entries-fields.html) in a [Global](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/globals.html).

I'd create a field called "Footer Links". At the bottom of the field settings page, expand the **Advanced** area and enable `Manage relations on a per-site basis`. This will allow you to have different links for each of your sites, if you wish.

Comment: Ah, of course. You are so right. I thought too that Globals would be the answer, but I could not see that Globals supported a multi-site environment. Now that I looked an extra time- I see it clearly. Thanks for guiding me ;-)